# How to export order data for reporting

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm wondering what the best way to export order data from Craft Commerce would be for the client's order and revenue reporting.

Ideally they'd like to be able to export a report after filtering by date on the Commerce > Orders screen, which I think would also be a great feature request.

For now it looks like Sprout Export might be the only/best option. I'm wondering if this has come up for anyone who might have other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could also export the data to a CSV with your own SQL commands. These commands could be created in a way to take parameter that your client could set through the CP.

You'd need to [create a plugin](https://pluginfactory.io/) with a [controller](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers) method that runs your SQL query. Take a look at the docs for more info on [querying the database](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/database).